# sql AND OR LIKE operator to display values

Tags: mysql, sql

This is I think a simple problem but not getting the solution yet. I would like to get the valid numbers only from a column as explained here.

Here the problem is to select one value

```
    SELECT absent_id FROM staff_attendance WHERE attendance_date='2017-02-06' AND absent_id='25'  AND school_id='1'
```

but absent_id table values store in

```
`absent_id`    
  1,12,25
```

Here, obviously,table is not desired as it is not valid number.

The desired result is

```
 absent_id 
     25
```

Comment: Fix your table structure. Normalize it.

Comment: Never, ever store data as comma separated items. It will only cause you lots of trouble.

Answer (score 0):

You should really normalizing your table structure. Never store multiple value in one row and column. This is one of the many issues of the denormalized design.

For now, you can use MySQL built-in `FIND_IN_SET`:

```
SELECT
  absent_id ids,
  '25' absent_id
FROM staff_attendance
WHERE attendance_date='2017-02-06'
AND find_in_set('25', absent_id)
AND school_id='1'
```

The above will work, but will be very slow if data set is large. It's because of the fact the MySQL can't use index on the column plus it's a string search operation which is bound to be slow.

Comment: `absent_id`    
  1,12,25 this is output

Comment: @arun - What do you mean?

Comment: the query execute values `absent_id`    
  1,12,25 this is output

Comment: You only are providing the value 25, so you can put it in the select part.

Answer (score 0):

If absent_id is `integer` datatype column.Then try like
this..

```
SELECT absent_id FROM staff_attendance WHERE attendance_date='2017-02-06' AND absent_id=25  AND school_id=1
```

Comment: integer values at time 1 value store